# How to return-tab large function name calls in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have code that requires **multiple inputs and outputs** and so when I call the function in my code, it **exceeds the width of my screen** and this makes it very **inconvenient to see all the variables being passed** in. I tried `return` and indenting until after the parentheses, but that **didn't really fix** it. Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

**Example:** Here is a typical function call. I have replaced the variable names with `x1` and `y1` for sake of privacy. What I'd like to be able to do is **split this function call into multiple lines.**

`[y1, y2, y3] = function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8);`

I tried calling the function as:

```
[y1, y2, y3] = function(x1, 
                        x2, 
                        x3, 
                        x4, 
                        x5, 
                        x6, 
                        x7, 
                        x8);
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Error: File: find_EC_DAPI_directory.m Line: 65 Column: 89
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

I searched Stack Overflow for this question, but none came up. Perhaps it was because I didn't search for it the right way, if so, please point me to the right direction.

Comment: See: [mcve]. I don't understand what you tried and why it "didn't really" fix it.

Comment: @excaza I've edited my question. Sorry about the ocnfusion.

Comment: In what way does that not solve the issue?

Comment: I've placed my error statement as well.

Comment: See: [Continue Long Statements on Multiple Lines](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[y1, y2, y3] = function(x1,...
                        x2,...
                        x3,...
                        x4,...
                        x5,...
                        x6,...
                        x7,...
                        x8);
```

Use "..." to have new lines

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html